# pandas rolling and ewm to completely ignore na and use last N valid data

Tags: python, pandas

Regarding the new `.rolling` and `.ewm` methods. I'm using pandas 0.19.0.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,np.nan, 3, 4, 5], 'B' : [1,2,3,np.nan, 4, 5]})
>>> df
     A    B
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  3.0
3  3.0  NaN
4  4.0  4.0
5  5.0  5.0

>>> df.rolling(window = 3).mean()
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  2.0
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  4.0  NaN
```

Desired output is to completely ignore the nan's, use the last 3 valid data, and leave the nan's at where they are.

```
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN # first two we don't have enough data
2  NaN  2.0 # B column is valid
3  2.0  NaN # completely ignore the nan in df.ix[2,'A'], take the mean of last 3 valid data
4  3.0  3.0
5  4.0  4.0
```

For `.ewm` we have a `ignore_na` parameter. And the code below gets what I want

```
output = df.ewm(com=2, ignore_na=True).mean()
output[df.isnull()] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the difficult part is that you want the last 3 valid data points.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().rolling(3).mean().reindex(x.index))
```

[image]

Comment: Do I definitely need `.reindex`? `df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().rolling(3).mean())` seems working as well

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, `.reindex` definitely needed